# How can I get a collection of all the Notification Area Icons?

Tags: winforms, powershell

I can create an icon using a script containing:

```
$objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$objNotifyIcon.Icon = "C:\MyIcon.ico"
```

But how can I check to see if the Icon is already there before creating a new one?

I thought something like:

```
$objNotifyIcon = $null
foreach ($icon in ???????) {
  if ($icon -eq "C:\MyIcon.ico") $objNotifyIcon = $icon
}
```

Any ideas what ??????? should be?

Comment: Why do you need to check existence of an icon in system tray? Probably you need to check `Visible` property of your `NotifyIcon` component.

Comment: It's the NotifyIcon variable I want to find out! I want to be able to call this script multiple times and don't want to have to remember the $objNotifyIcon